# Using .xhtml and JSP in same application

Tags: jsp, xhtml, jsf-2, facelets

I found this [Mixing JSP and XHTML (Facelets) in JSF2 Project - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936110/mixing-jsp-and-xhtml-facelets-in-jsf2-project-possible) when I searched for a way to use .jsp and .xhtml together.

That question is answered with a link to a FAQ that states that I must use prefix mapping but I can't figure out how. I understand that I must add facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS but that wording on "You have to use prefix mapping" is what I cant understand.

Basically i'm supposed to acess my page with /faces/ included like: "http://localhost:8080/webapp/faces/mypage.xhtml"

But if I try to add /faces/ manually it goes 404. And I'm not sure if it should be added automatically when running the app or not.

My welcome file is a html page that uses: `<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onload="window.location='/portal/login/login.xhtml'">`

should it really be .xhtml and not .jsf?

Prior to trying to blend with the JSP pages and only trying out JSF2 I ran it like this succesfully:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Using /faces/* instead seems to be a must but I just don't understand how to use it properly.

I'm trying it like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Use extensions mapping for Faces servlet -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

This regards a big application built with pure jsp pages and jsp pages with JSF 1.2. Basically i'm converting all the jsf pages into jsf2 and thus xhtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While above suggestion actually did work I didnt want to change the urls everywere and I got the preface mapping to work by using the correct parameter.

does not work:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

works:

```
<!-- Facelets pages will use the .xhtml extension -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefix mapping is a folder mapping like `/faces/*`. Suffix mapping is an extension mapping like `*.jsf`. Your welcome file is using a hacky JS line which changes the location (why don't you just specify that URL instead in `<welcome-file>`?). This location URL should also include `/faces` mapping.

Another (IMO better) solution in JSF 2.0 is to use `*.jsf` instead and remove all other context param configuration and leave it default. JSF will scan for `page.xhtml` first and if it doesn't exist, then it will scan for `page.jsp`. So, all you have in `web.xml` should be:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I haven't answered it in the question which you linked because I didn't knew that at that moment.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

Comment: Thank you! This works well. Reason behind using the html page is (I think) to clear cache and some other stuff that's unrelated to the login page so it's a design choice by someone. I don't understand why I couldn't find this information somewhere I tried to solve this for long time!