# Mixing JSF1.2 and JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-1.2

The legacy web app is using JSF1.2 with facelets.  Due to the size of the app, upgrading it to JSF2 would take extensive effort.  Is it possible to mix JSF1.2 and JSF2 in the same web app during the transition period?

I read this post: [Mixing JSP and XHTML (Facelets) in JSF2 Project - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936110/mixing-jsp-and-xhtml-facelets-in-jsf2-project-possible)

but it seems to be related more to converting a JSP app to JSF2?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is it possible to mix JSF1.2 and JSF2 in the same web app during the transition period?*

No.

You can mix JSP and Facelets in one web application, but you can definitely not mix different JSF impls/versions in the same web application. It would only result in class loading conflicts in all colors because multiple different versions of the very same classes are then present in the runtime classpath.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: How about having JSF1.2(with facelet) in one war and JSF2 in another war but in the same ear.  Will that work, or will it also encounter lots of class loading conflicts as you described?

Comment: That'll work just fine. It are physically separate web applications.